# Extract the middle character from a string in excel using formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to extract the middle character from a string in excel.Is there any way to achieve this task using excel formula ? Like if i have string with even length then extracting middle two character or else if its length is odd then extracting single middle character as shown below in the image.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works and it's very simple:

```
=MID(A2,ROUNDPUP(LEN(A5)/2,0),IF(MOD(LEN(A2),2)=0,2,1))
```

---

### Explanation:

Considering "**abcde**" string, it would be:

- `ROUNDPUP(LEN(A5)/2,0)` is the position we want to start extracting (e.g 3).
- `IF(MOD(LEN(A2),2)=0,2,1)` is how many characters we need. `MOD` is used to determine whether the lenght (`LEN`) is **EVEN** or **ODD**, and return 1 or 2 depending on the result.
- `MID(A2, 3, 1)` is used to get a substring from *A2* content, in this example, starting in the third position, extracting only 1 character (because it's odd).

If it was "**abcd**", it would result in `MID(A2, 2, 2)`, which means starting from the second character ("b"), takes two characters ("bc").

Answer (score 3):

The following works:

```
=IF(MOD(LEN(A2),2) = 0,MID(A2,INT(LEN(A2)/2),2),MID(A2,1+INT(LEN(A2)/2),1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Shortest formula possible:

```
=MID(A1,LEN(A1)/2+0.5,2-MOD(LEN(A1),2))
```

This exploits the MID function only taking the integer part of its arguments.